# Apache camel : BeanIo : dyanmic mapping is not working and throwing error

Tags: apache-camel

```
.to("dataformat:beanio:unmarshal?mapping=("{{file name}}"?streamName=xyz")
```

where mapping <. have to keep dynamic and passed as input value to rout through parameter/properties 
is not working for me and

Answer (score 1):

You should have searched the internet, SO or the Camel website for keywords such as dynamic to.

See this FAQ:
http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html